# How to tune ConversationalRetrievalChain to not convert the standalone question for hey, hello, etc greetings in a middle of the conversation?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, openai-api, langchain, google-cloud-vertex-ai, large-language-model

I am building a chatbot for an event using ConversationalRetrievalChain from langchain and Vertex AI as LLM model. Also, I have use FAISS as vector store with VoyageAI embeddings.

The ConversationalRetrievalChain seems to be working great when it comes to the standalone question which is generated but I found one big flaw in that. It seems to not know, how to respond to "hello", "hey" types of greetings.

Use Case being - Let's say if a user has asked a few questions about burger shops. And tomorrow, if he/she comes back and just types "Hello", ConversationalRetrievalChain is converting that to reply for burger shop and not treating it as a greeting.

Options:

1. I understand some people might think I should clear the memory with new date but that's not an ideal scenario for messaging. If i am chatting at 11.59pm so at 12' it would lose all its memory. That's not proper.
2. Hardcode hello, hi responses (I saw this option in a github comment raised) but that is wrong. How would I know if the user just types heyyyyyy ?

Please check out my code if you find something -

```
voyage = VoyageEmbeddings(model='voyage-01', voyage_api_key='token')
db = FAISS.from_documents(docs, voyage)

retriever = db.as_retriever(search_type='mmr', search_kwargs={"k": 5})

llm = VertexAI(
    model_name='text-bison@002,
    max_output_tokens=2000,
    temperature=0.2
)

_template = """Given the following conversation and a follow up input, rephrase the follow up input to be a standalone question or a statement.Strictly generate standalone question in English language only.
Please don't repharse hi, hello, hey, whatsup or similar greetings. Please keep them as is.
    
Chat History:
{chat_history}
Follow Up Input: {question}
Standalone question:"""

CONDENSE_QUESTION_PROMPT = PromptTemplate.from_template(_template)

template = """You are a chatbot assistant for the ABCD festival (Also known as Anybody can dance).You are having a friendly conversation with a customer who wants to know more about ABCD festival.If a question is asked out of context, please warmly suggest that you can answer questions only about ABCD festival.Please generate a warm, friendly and exciting response.If you don't know the answer, please apologize and state that you do not know.You should strictly answer based on the context below.
{context}

Current conversation:
{chat_history}
Human: {question}
AI Assistant:"""

PROMPT = PromptTemplate(template=template, input_variables=[
                        'context', 'chat_history', 'question'])

memory = ConversationBufferMemory(
    memory_key="chat_history", ai_prefix="AI Assistant", return_messages=True)

chat = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
    llm, retriever, memory=memory, condense_question_prompt=CONDENSE_QUESTION_PROMPT,combine_docs_chain_kwargs={"prompt": PROMPT}, verbose=False)
```

When asked the following conversation:

```
x = chat({"question":"Hello"})
print(f"Question: {x['question']} Answer: {x['answer']}")

x = chat({"question":"Are there any burger shops?"})
print(f"Question: {x['question']} Answer: {x['answer']}")

x = chat({"question":"Are they best?"})
print(f"Question: {x['question']} Answer: {x['answer']}")

x = chat({"question":"Hello"})
print(f"Question: {x['question']} Answer: {x['answer']}")
```

Output is:

```
Question: Hello Answer:  Hello there! How can I assist you today?

Question: Are there any burger shops? Answer:  Certainly! There are a few burger places at the ABCD festival. At the Amuse Zone, you'll find The Burger Maker, a laid-back kiosk where you can enjoy delicious burgers and have a great time. In the Entertain Zone, there's Highjoint, an award-winning burger joint that offers a unique blend of high-end ingredients and cooking techniques. And at the Thrill Zone, you can try G.O.A.T., which brings you homegrown Indian burgers that are truly the Greatest Of All Time! Let me know if you'd like more details about any of these burger places or if you have any other questions about the ABCD festival.

Question: Are they best? Answer:  That's a tough question as everyone has different preferences when it comes to burgers. However, Highjoint in the Entertain Zone has won awards for its exceptional burgers. They are known for blending high-quality ingredients with innovative cooking techniques to create truly unique and delicious burgers. If you're a burger enthusiast, I highly recommend giving Highjoint a try!

Question: Hello Answer:  At the Amuse Zone, you'll find The Burger Maker, a laid-back kiosk where you can enjoy delicious burgers and have a great time. In the Entertain Zone, there's Highjoint, an award-winning burger joint that offers a unique blend of high-end ingredients and cooking techniques. And at the Thrill Zone, you can try G.O.A.T., which brings you homegrown Dubai burgers that are truly the Greatest Of All Time!
```

Comment: Hi @Rush W.,based on my understanding,as a workaround you can consider using an,if-else statement to check if the user's message is a common greeting or not before sending it to the chatbot. You can hardcode a list of common greetings and their corresponding replies. If the user's message is not in the hardcoded list, you can send it to the chatbot. Alternatively, you can use natural language processing (NLP) libraries to determine if the user's message is a greeting or not. This approach eliminates the need to create a hardcoded list and makes the process more efficient.